# job send email to developers upon complexion and include DBAs if it fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, jobs, database-mail, error-handling

I have a job that sends an email to an operator ([which contains a list of emails within it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152007/send-email-to-multiple-recipients)) upon complexion.

Some of these people that are on that list are the developers who build everything in that job.

I am the DBA but I am also in the list.

[image]

QUESTION:

Is there a way to make this job send an email to those guys upon complexion, and to the DBAs only if the job fails?

So, upon complexion of the job, which has 4 steps,
the developers will always get an email, (the job is scheduled to run every day),
and if (by any reason) the job fails, the developers AND  the DBAs will get and email.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, add a job step called for example mail dba.

In that job step you put the `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`

An example job step

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'DBA',  
    @recipients = 'some_email@somedomain.com',  
    @body = 'The Job Failed.',  
    @subject = 'Automated Error Message' ;
```

Then you edit every step of the job to go to job step mail dba when it fails.